# How to read fields of type "password"

Tags: soql, rest-api, passwords

I am making an api call and using a SOQL query to get some data from one of our accounts in Salesforce.  One of the fields i'm retrieving is of type "password", and so when i pull the value down, i can only see all asterisks (it looks like **********).
So, is there a way to read the value of a password type field in an api call instead of just reading it as all asterisks?

Comment: do you have access to the target salesforce org? if so check if the field u pull is of type text(encrypted) if so you need to have "view encrypted data" permission on the user profile

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I didn't have the "view encrypted data" permission...

Comment: Before I get yelled by some members here I have my comment as an answer :)

Comment: @MnZ I couldn't mark his answer when it was just a comment!

Comment: @TylerJones Hey, could you share the query that you used as I am also trying kinda same one wherein I am unable to query the password in the SOQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have access to the target salesforce org?

Check if the field u pull is of type text(encrypted), you need to have "view encrypted data" permission on the user profile